# NG2-Charts only displayed after refreshing page

Tags: angular, ng2-charts

I am doing a project in angular and I am using Angular 11.

My problem here is with [ng2-charts](https://valor-software.com/ng2-charts/). In short, an api-request call to the backend is made to populate the chart with data.

I think I know where the problem lies in but with no idea to solve this:

The template (so the chart) is initialized without any data. So the template already exists when the api call is made to load the data, which makes the chart itself blank. When I refresh the data already exists and the data is loaded as intended.

As you can see,

```js
export class ChartComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  public doughnutChartLabels: Label[] = [];
  public doughnutChartData: MultiDataSet = [
    []
  ];
  public doughutColors: any[] = [];
  public pieChartColors: Array <any> = [{
    backgroundColor: []
  }];
  public doughnutChartType: ChartType = 'doughnut';
  private subscriptions: Subscription[] = [];
  public loaded: boolean = false;

  constructor(private pLanguageService: PLanguageService,
              private analyticsService: AnalyticsService,
              private subscriptionService: SubscriptionService,
              public changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.subscriptionService.unsubscribeParam(this.subscriptions);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.initData();
  }

  private initData(): void {
    const subscription: Subscription = this.pLanguageService
      .findAll()
      .pipe(switchMap((pLanguage: Planguage[]) => {
        return this.analyticsService.getUsageStatisticsOfPLanguages();
      }))
      .subscribe((data: UsageStatistics) => {
        this.initChart(data);
      });
    this.subscriptions.push(subscription);
  }

  private initChart(statistics: UsageStatistics): void {
    this.initUsagePercentages(statistics);
    this.visualizeChart();
    console.log("initialization done");
  }

  private visualizeChart(): void {
    this.pieChartColors = [{backgroundColor: this.doughutColors}];
    this.loaded = true;
  }

  private initUsagePercentages(statistics: UsageStatistics): void {
    for(let i = 0; i < statistics.planguages.length; i++) {
      this.doughnutChartLabels.push(statistics.planguages[i].language);
      this.doughnutChartData[0].push(statistics.numberSubmissions[i]);
      this.doughutColors.push(`${statistics.planguages[i].color}`);
    }
  }
}
```

And here is my template for this component

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="loaded">
  <div id="chart">
    <div class="card shadow mb-4">
      <div class="card-header d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
        <h4 style="margin-bottom: 4px;margin-top: 4px;">Language use distribution</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="chart-area">
          <div style="display: block;">
            <canvas baseChart
                    [data]="doughnutChartData"
                    [labels]="doughnutChartLabels"
                    [chartType]="doughnutChartType"
                    [colors]="pieChartColors">
            </canvas>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

So what I am trying right now is to prevent the template "from loading" before the data is available - but that does not work.

My goal is to update the chart (or refresh the component) without refreshing the entire window. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You manipulate the same object, that why angular don't update components again.

```
this.doughnutChartData[0].push(statistics.numberSubmissions[i]);
```

Simple trick here is assign the object to new reference:

```
for(let i = 0; i < statistics.planguages.length; i++) {
      this.doughnutChartLabels.push(statistics.planguages[i].language);
      this.doughnutChartData[0].push(statistics.numberSubmissions[i]);
      this.doughutColors.push(`${statistics.planguages[i].color}`);
    }
```

to:

```
   for(let i = 0; i < statistics.planguages.length; i++) {          
          ...
        }
   this.doughnutChartLabels = [...this.doughnutChartLabels];
   this.doughnutChartData= [...this.doughnutChartData];
```

Comment: Does not work unfortunately, but thanks for the tip. I tried messing around with viewchild and trying to update the chart but does not work either.

Comment: strange, in in our project, it work as expected. Can you help to reproduce it on? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hnpdsw, then others can investigate more deeper.

Comment: I solved the problem by switching to ngx-charts. It worked there.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this.chart.chart.update() after you push doughnutChartData.